# JQGrid AutoComplete Configuration With ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jqgrid, autocomplete

I am having trouble understanding how to implement the JQGrid JQAutoComplete control using ASP.NET Web Forms. The data for my grid comes from a DataTable and I would like to load my AutoComplete DataSource from an existing column in that same DataTable.

I have defined my column like this:

```
<trirand:JQGridColumn 
                HeaderText="System Id"
                DataField="system_id"
                Editable="true"
                EditType="AutoComplete"
                EditorControlID="SystemId_AutoComplete">
</trirand:JQGridColumn>
```

My AutoComplete control is defined like this:

```
<trirand:JQAutoComplete
                runat="server"
                ID="SystemId_AutoComplete"
                DisplayMode="ControlEditor" 
                DataTextField="system_id"
/>
```

In my code, I then use the following to attempt to bind the DataTable to the AutoComplete control.

```
SystemId_AutoComplete.DataSource = myDataTableGoesHere;
SystemId_AutoComplete.DataBind();
```

However, upon implementation .NET throws the error “cannot find column [system_id]” even though it’s one of my column names.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
<trirand:JQGridColumn 
                HeaderText="System Id"
                DataField="system_id"
                Editable="true"
                EditType="AutoComplete"
                EditorControlID="SystemId_AutoComplete">
</trirand:JQGridColumn>
```

with

```
<trirand:JQGridColumn 
                HeaderText="System Id"
                DataField="system_id"
                Searchable="true" 
                SearchType="AutoComplete"
                SearchControlID="SystemId_AutoComplete">
</trirand:JQGridColumn>
```

Check Searching/Filtering in the left pane of [Documentation](http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnet.aspx)